# whitelisting files with nodejs to hide sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, whitelist, source-maps

I recently integrated my error logging with [getsentry.com](http://getsentry.com). My problem now it that I had to generate a source map so basically anyone with a modern browser can now see my original code fully commented.

I'm looking for a way to allow access to the source map files to only specific ips and/or subnets with nodejs, since I'm using heroku.

I imagine it will involve using something like https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-ipfilter or https://www.npmjs.org/package/ip. But still trying to think of how to create a middle where to 'route' to the files and evaluate the ips

Comment: The package you link to is middleware.